# Array a tabla PHP

Tags: php, html, array

Tengo el siguiente array:

```
Array ( [0] => Ficha 001 [nombre] => Ficha 001 [1] => Supermercados [matriz_nombre] => Supermercados [2] => 1000 cc [columna_nombre] => 1000 cc [3] => Heineken [fila_nombre] => Heineken [4] => 15000 [valor_fila_columna] => 15000 ) Array ( [0] => Ficha 001 [nombre] => Ficha 001 [1] => Supermercados [matriz_nombre] => Supermercados [2] => 650 cc [columna_nombre] => 650 cc [3] => Pulp [fila_nombre] => Pulp [4] => 8000 [valor_fila_columna] => 8000 ) Array ( [0] => Ficha 001 [nombre] => Ficha 001 [1] => Supermercados [matriz_nombre] => Supermercados [2] => 300 cc [columna_nombre] => 300 cc [3] => Puro Sol [fila_nombre] => Puro Sol [4] => 7500 [valor_fila_columna] => 7500 )
```

Que tiene la siguiente estructura:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y necesito dibujar la tabla html de la siguiente manera:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cabe recalcar que los valores se cargaran dinámicamente de una base de datos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes recorrer el array con los datos y crear un array donde vas guardando las diferentes columnas que vas a tener (sin conocer a priori cuántas o cuáles son) y otro array donde guardas los datos que vas a mostrar, guardando en cada fila el nombre y el dato en la posición correspondiente a la columna.

```
$data = array(
        '1' => array(
            'ficha_nombre' => 'Ficha 001',
            'matriz_nombre' => 'Supermercados',
            'columna_nombre' => '1000 cc',
            'fila_nombre' => 'Heineken',
            'valor_fila_columna' => 15000
        ),
        '2' => array(
            'ficha_nombre' => 'Ficha 001',
            'matriz_nombre' => 'Ficha 001',
            'columna_nombre' => '650 cc',
            'fila_nombre' => 'Pulp',
            'valor_fila_columna' => 8000
        ),
     '3' => array(
            'ficha_nombre' => 'Ficha 001',
            'matriz_nombre' => 'Ficha 001',
            'columna_nombre' => '300 cc',
            'fila_nombre' => 'Puro Sol',
            'valor_fila_columna' => 7500
        )
    );

$a_colsname = array(); 
array_push($a_colsname, "Nombre");
$filas = array();
foreach ($data as $dato) {
   $colname = $dato["columna_nombre"];
    if (!in_array($colname, $a_colsname)) {
       array_push($a_colsname, $colname);
    }
    $fila = array();
    $fila[0] = $dato["fila_nombre"];
    $posicion_col = array_search ( $colname , $a_colsname );
    $fila[$posicion_col] = $dato["valor_fila_columna"];
    $filas[] = $fila;
}
//var_dump($a_colsname);
//var_dump($filas);
echo "<table>";
echo "<tr>";
for ($i=0; $i<count($a_colsname); $i++) {
    echo "<td>".$a_colsname[$i]."</td>";
}
echo "</tr>";
for ($i=0; $i<count($filas); $i++) {
    echo "<tr>";
    for ($j=0; $j<count($a_colsname); $j++){
        if (empty($filas[$i][$j])) {
            echo "<td></td>";          
        } else {
           echo "<td>".$filas[$i][$j]."</td>";
        }
    }
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Resultado:

```
Nombre   1000 cc    650 cc  300 cc
Heineken 15000      
Pulp                8000    
Puro Sol                     7500
```

Comment: Excelente aporte @Carmen, Muchas gracias!

Comment: Un placer, para eso estamos :)

Answer (score 3):

Para empezar tienes el `Array` mal hecho.

Así es cómo yo lo haría:

```
$array = array(
        '1' => array(
            'ficha_nombre' => 'Ficha 001',
            'matriz_nombre' => 'Supermercados',
            'columna_nombre' => '1000 cc',
            'fila_nombre' => 'Heineken',
            'valor_fila_columna' => 15000
        ),
        '2' => array(
            'ficha_nombre' => 'Ficha 001',
            'matriz_nombre' => 'Ficha 001',
            'columna_nombre' => '650 cc',
            'fila_nombre' => 'Pulp',
            'valor_fila_columna' => 8000
        ),
    );
```

Dónde `1` y `2` es cada fila de la `Base de Datos`.

Para visualizarlo en el `HTML`, lo que yo haría sería recorrer el `array` directamente de la siguiente manera:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>ficha_nombre</td>
            <td>matriz_nombre</td>
            <td>columna_nombre</td>
            <td>fila_nombre</td>
            <td>valor_fila_columna</td>
        </tr>
        <?php foreach($array as $element): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?= $element['ficha_nombre']?></td>
            <td><?= $element['matriz_nombre']?></td>
            <td><?= $element['columna_nombre']?></td>
            <td><?= $element['fila_nombre']?></td>
            <td><?= $element['valor_fila_columna']?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </table>
```

Si tienes alguna duda no dudes en preguntar!

Comment: Gracias @Csc99 ! Pero mi duda esta en como dibujar los valores de  "columna_nombre" de forma horizontal como en la segunda figura.